# Javascript text/number replace with image

Tags: javascript, string, image, replace

Im new to javascript and trying to figure this out, building a little binary clock thing (I know terribly geeky)

I have written most of it, the only thing i want to do now is that i have my strings exporting as a series of 0's and 1's and now i would like those numbers to be replaced with my images 0.png and 1.png which are in the same directory...

below is my code so far, i would really like for it to execute within the same function...

```
function binClock ( )
{
    var currentTime = new Date ( );

    var currentYear = currentTime.getFullYear ( );
    var currentMonth = currentTime.getMonth ( ) +1;
    var currentDate = currentTime.getDate ( );
    var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );
    var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes ( );
    var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds ( );

    currentYear = currentYear.toString(2);
    currentMonth = currentMonth.toString(2);
    currentDate = currentDate.toString(2);
    currentHours = currentHours.toString(2);
    currentMinutes = currentMinutes.toString(2);
    currentSeconds = currentSeconds.toString(2);

    document.getElementById("year").firstChild.nodeValue = currentYear;
    document.getElementById("month").firstChild.nodeValue = currentMonth;
    document.getElementById("date").firstChild.nodeValue = currentDate;
    document.getElementById("hour").firstChild.nodeValue = currentHours;
    document.getElementById("min").firstChild.nodeValue = currentMinutes;
    document.getElementById("second").firstChild.nodeValue = currentSeconds;
}
```

I am running this on body with:

```
onload="binClock(); setInterval('binClock()', 1000 )"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an IMG element somewhere in the document with ID `your_img`:

```
var path_to_img = ...
var image = document.getElementById('your_img');
image.setAttribute('src', path_to_img);
```

where `path_to_img` should be set to the URL to `0.png` or `1.png` depending on some condition.

If there is no IMG element you can create it and add it to DOM like this:

```
var path_to_img = ...;
var parent_element_id = ...;
var parent = document.getElementById(parent_element_id);
var image = document.createElement('IMG');
image.setAttribute('src', path_to_img);
parent.appendChild(image);
```

where `parent_element_id` is the ID of the element under which you wish to add the new IMG element.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is my example how you could do it, I am using JQuery but you can replace easily with the javascript DOM method.

```
new Date().getFullYear().toString(2).split('')
.forEach(function(data) { 
    $('#year').append('<img src="../img/digit' + data + '.png');
});
```

// Edit modified my example + small demo
http://jsfiddle.net/staar2/nXuHV/1/

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out my own way - in ways that i understand... as im learning i want to get the syntax and everything so i can understand what it is that im doing and putting in

```
var currentYear = currentTime.getFullYear ( );
var currentMonth = currentTime.getMonth ( ) +1;
var currentDate = currentTime.getDate ( );
var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );
var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes ( );
var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds ( );

currentYear = currentYear.toString(2);
currentMonth = currentMonth.toString(2);
currentDate = currentDate.toString(2);
currentHours = currentHours.toString(2);
currentMinutes = currentMinutes.toString(2);
currentSeconds = currentSeconds.toString(2);

currentYear = currentYear.replace(/0/g,"<img src='0.png' />");
currentYear = currentYear.replace(/1/g,'<img src="1.png" />');

currentMonth = currentMonth.replace(/0/g,"<img src='0.png' />");
currentMonth = currentMonth.replace(/1/g,'<img src="1.png" />');

currentDate = currentDate.replace(/0/g,"<img src='0.png' />");
currentDate = currentDate.replace(/1/g,'<img src="1.png" />');

currentHours = currentHours.replace(/0/g,"<img src='0.png' />");
currentHours = currentHours.replace(/1/g,'<img src="1.png" />');

currentMinutes = currentMinutes.replace(/0/g,"<img src='0.png' />");
currentMinutes = currentMinutes.replace(/1/g,'<img src="1.png" />');

currentSeconds = currentSeconds.replace(/0/g,"<img src='0.png' />");
currentSeconds = currentSeconds.replace(/1/g,'<img src="1.png" />');

document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = currentYear;
document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = currentMonth;
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = currentDate;
document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = currentHours;
document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = currentMinutes;
document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = currentSeconds;`
```

you can see it running at 
http://www.simonbrowndesign.com/test/datestamp.php